# Cannot connect to .mdf database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I've tried everything but I can not access/change/modify my database. I created it in visual studio with .mdf. I am new at using SQL database so I will be glad if you can help me. As I said, I created that database, in visual studio but I can not create a connection with that database.

In web config :

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In cs I used that sql connection string:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
```

And I have this error:

*An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\mcan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\App_Data\Database.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.*

---

I've made some changes:

In web config :

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and in cs:

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;");
```

Now it gives that error:

```
*Server Error in '/WebSite1' Application. Cannot open database |DataDirectory|Database.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'mcan-PC\mcan'. *
```

Comment: @SLaks - Did you? There are 3 possibilities mentioned in the message. Your answer assumes one.

Comment: @MartinSmith: That's not a UNC share, and he said that he already created the file.

Comment: @SLaks - But could still be a permissions issue. No?

Comment: I think the error message is clean.

Comment: that user has permission to it. if you understand the problem and be able to help then i wait your comments

Answer (score 2):

As the error clearly states, that database is already connected to SQL Server.
You can't have two databases with the same name on the same server.

Comment: i just try to access that database from one place, why there is another connection? i can not access and modify it, what should i do then?

Comment: The database is already in SQL Server.  You should either remove it from SQL server or connect to it by name instead of trying to re-attach it.

Comment: could you explain the way to connect to it by name?

Comment: Use `Initial Catalog` instead of `AttachDBFilename`

Comment: than another problem occurs:
Cannot open database "|DataDirectory|Database.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'mcan-PC\mcan'.

Comment: @MertYigin: Check the permissions in SQL Server.  (use SSMS)

Comment: i check all the grant columns for my user, but when i press OK and reopen permissions they will be disappered?

Comment: I don't know; ask a separate question about the permissioning on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that your mdf file doesn't have permissions set for Authenticated Users. Navigate to your .mdf file, right click and go to Properties then the Security tab. Check if the Authenticated Users appears in 'Group or user names'. If it doesn't then you'll have to click on Edit then Add and type in Authenticated Users. Then you'll hit Check names and OK. After that enable full control for Authenticated Users. You'll have to repeat this for the .ldf file too.

Comment: i've checked and Authenticated Users appears in 'Group or user names'.

Comment: When you select Authenticated Users and look under the Permissions list, is Full control checked under the Allow column?

Comment: Yes, there is System, mcan-PC\mcan and mcan-PC\Administrators, the owner is the mcan-PC\mcan, and they all have Full control checked under the Allow column